# Windows 7 reboot loop after migrating to VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

We used Windows 7 32bit in KVM before, but want to migrate to VirtualBox-ose:

```
qemu-img convert Windows_7-KVM.qcow2 -O raw Windows7.img
vboxmanage convertdd Windows7.img Windows7.vdi
```

But when we try to boot the windows 7 guest, it goes in a "reboot loop"... says "loading files" then reboot..

We already tried: 
 - Enable/Disable IO APIC
 - IDE / SATA controllers
 - Tried to go to "safe mode", by pressing F8 like a "maniac".. but we gues only rebooted..

**Our question:** how can we debug, solve this problem with the reboot loop of the windows 7 guest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting to VMDK works:
1. qemu-img convert -f qcow2 Win7.qcow2 -O vmdk -o compat6 Win7.vmdk
2. IDE controller needed
3. in "Device manager" delete all the IDE drivers
4. From now on you can put the disk image to SATA (if using ext4 - host I/O cache need to be turned on), then boot

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem. My HDD was set to SATA0 in the STORAGE settings by default. I changed it to IDE and pointed to the path where my win7 *.vdi HDD was. It booted!